# Visor imágenes 360 con modelos virtuales en posiciones reales en Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy intentando hacer un visor de fotos 360 de Realidad Virtual. Quiero poner modelos virtuales con coordenadas reales del objeto de forma que ese objeto virtual solape el de la imagen 360.

Para ello, tengo el yaw, pitch y roll de la imagen (su rotación) y las coordenadas x,y,z del objeto. Estas coordenadas son relativas con respecto al punto donde ha sido tomada la foto.

Mi problema es que, teniendo en cuenta el cambio de eje de coordenadas en unity, los objetos no se colocan donde deberían. Os explico:

Tengo los datos topográficos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cojo la primera imagen, que está marca con Xrel, Yrel y Zrel igual a 0. Esta imagen la pongo en Unity como skybox.

Al material Skybox le pongo una rotación de 108.254, justo el valor del Yaw (rotación con respecto al eje Y) de la imagen.

Con los datos que tengo de los objetos (farolas, señales...etc) voy a crear esferas en Unity y, dándole esos valores de coordenadas, deberían de solaparse en la foto con el objeto en cuestión. Por ejemplo, la señal marcada en amarillo. Tiene de coordenadas x=2.506, y =8.620, z = 0.609. Como Unity tiene los ejes cambiados, le aplico cambio de coordenadas y coloco dicha esfera en: x=-2.506, y =0.609 y z = -8.620.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que la esfera no se coloca sobre la señal, es que ni se queda cerca. Y he probado toda las combinaciones posibles con los ejes. Estoy ya en modo desesperada ON. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cual puede ser mi error?

¡Muchas gracias!

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Elena. Bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tu pregunta se considera muy amplia y es motivo de cierre. Si ves [ask] verás que tienes que proveer de un ejemplo de lo que has intentado y por que no resultó. Un saludo

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo actual y describir mas a fondo cual es el problema que tienes

Comment: ¡Hecho! Gracias :)